# Minimalistic Statements

Tags: logic

Is "for some(at least 1 tupel) $a,b\in\mathbb{Set}$

$a\circ b=b\circ a$" a statement?

And if so, why would only "$a\circ b=b\circ a$" be no statement?

Comment: Check the definition of statement.

Comment: I never saw the word "statement" used this way before, but a standard definition says that a wff is a _sentence_ if and only if it has no free variables.